# Help with the error K2_A2 Coupling to shorted-out inductor L5 and looking for pointers for better modelling SWR

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transformer, ltspice, ham-radio

I have an RF linear amplifier kit that I am trying to better understand.  The problem I am having is that my driver/transmitter is seeing a non matching impedance.  To better understand the amplifier and what affects the impedance it presents to a 50 Ohm source, I decided to learn about transformers and mosfets by modelling them in LTSpice.  The below schematic is basically my amplifier in LTSpice.  The values of inductance on the coils are made up, but the ratio of inductance in the transformers are not.  In the below circuit, the series resistance in the inductors is .000001 ohms .

I want to measure V(RFIN)/L(L2) at various frequencies and make sure that it is 50 Ohms.

What is the primary driver of source impedance?  I believe it would be the resister R, would this vary by frequency?  I would like to experiment by adding capacitors and inductors, as well as vary resister R, but wonder how accurate ltspice is at HF frequencies?

The main issue all this comes from is fixing the swr my radio complains about as well as understanding ltspice simulation/limitations.

Hopefully, people can post the areas I would need to dig deeper on/understand better.  For instance, someone mentioned to me that the mosfets have capacitance , but weren't sure if this was between the gate and source?  Would this capacitance affect my swr and/or is it properly described in the mosfet model to carry over to a plot of V(RFIN)/L(L2) on various frequencies.  Just wondering how good ltspice really is for hf modelling/experimenting.

Below is my ltspice model of the schmadic as well as a graph of impediance at frequencies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: LTSpice may balk at inductors having 0 ohm resistance. Add a small amount of series resistance to avoid this kind of error. In your circuit for example, L4 is driven from a voltage source. If L4 is a pure inductor of 0 ohms, you get an error.

Comment: Barev.  Do you have any kit details or link?  the schematic above won't work.

Comment: @glen_geek All the inductors have a series resistance of  .000001 Ohms.

Comment: @Barev Take a look at this link...

http://wa5bdu.blogspot.com/2019/03/70-w-ebay-mosfet-hf-amplifier.html

One problem is that the kit came with no instructions ; but by following a number of website such as the one above , it is showed/described to work.  There are also videos.  It is not clean, but works (with high SWR).  The schematic is in the lower part of the above  link.

Answer (score 2):

The Gates cannot be connected to the battery. There must be some trimpots to each that are high R followed by low RC filters to match the AC source impedance for good VSWR or Return Loss.

Vsig has some source impedance which is then transformed by \$n^2\$ turns ratio .

[image]

The example [is taken from a 600W RF amp.](https://qrpblog.com/product/a600-hf-vhf-600w-linear-amplifier-kit-v2-0/)

Comment: The actual circuit I created this simulation from has a trim pot that is used to set a bias voltage on the mosfets.  That can be adjusted.  The same bias voltage is set on both mosfets, creating a noisy amplifier.  In my circuit, I simplified this by putting a small battery in place of the 3.7 volts that the trim pots achieve.  I was wondering why LTSpice wont let me set it in such a away, seemingly just like the original circuit.

Comment: Voltage sources are 0 Ohms.  You need a series R then a cap ideally is a 0hms AC at RF.  Then trim the voltage.  The better way is shown in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check the connections. The way you show your picture makes me think that what we see is not the final picture, and that there are "stray" wires that may short out the `L5` inductor. It will do you good to clean it up, and also to the people trying to decipher it while helping.

In LTspice (possibly other SPICEs, too), elements that have their pins grounded are discarded from the matrix to avoid encumbrance. Having a coupling statement involving a shorted out (disabled) element results in the solver not knowing what element to look for (since it's discarded).

Not lastly, `R4` and `C1` are completely useless, as is `C2` (unless there is some `Rser` specified in `V3`). Be sure to check [glen_geek's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581501/help-with-the-error-k2-a2-coupling-to-shorted-out-inductor-l5-and-looking-for-po#comment1522012_581501), unless you already have fixed that by adding `Rser` to wither `V2` or `L4`.

As for how accurate or reliable LTspice is, that's a matter of the designer: any simulation will be as good as the consituent elements and the build. Otherwise, LTspice (and not only) will happily simulate THz, and is (proven to be) very reliable.

Comment: Those stray wires were where I was testing out the connection of V3 to the gates.  It turns out, V3 only connects to the center of the transformer.  I found that by buying another unassembled kit and looking at the circuit board.  I previously thought V3 also connected to the gates.  R4 is probably there because it was part of a trim pot circuit that delivered a variable voltage.  I choose 3.7 volts and added V3 in its place.  I can delete R4.  C1 and C2 were there because the original circuit had them.  My intent was to replicate the original circuit and investigate impedance and current.

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian However you look at it, the error is about a coupled shorted inductor, which can be either with wires, or with a voltage source without `Rser` (or similar). Yet the schematic you're showing has nothing of the sort. That's why I said "*makes me think that what we see is not the final picture*". The error and the schematic don't match, but the error is about what I said. Also, when transcribing real schematics it's useful to remember that SPICE world is nothing but an approximation, so fidelity is never achieved, therefore simplifications are often used.

Comment: @"a concerned citizen"   I updated the question.  The circuit compiles and has no errors.  The original circuit is buried in here  http://wa5bdu.blogspot.com/2019/03/70-w-ebay-mosfet-hf-amplifier.html   I can't make sense of some very important details.  I feel ltspice will show some impedance while my swr meter will show something else.  At the moment though, I am blowing mosfets more than Id like

Comment: @JeffreyEdwardMessikian That schematic is awfully drawn: you can't tell where there are connections and where there are not. I wouldn't trust that, honestly. I can understand how you might have ended up with that error. Also, when using the ping operator, `@`, use it with `@<TAB>` to cycle between a list of the available names. If none appears then there is no need for `@`. If it is needed, then the names should be used as they appear with `<TAB>`, without spaces.